# Fade in and out elements with css3's transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a div in my body

```
<div id="one" style="background-image: url(img/1.png)"></div>
```

when an event fires it should do the following

```
if(dragLeft < 270 && dragTop < 230) { 
  $('#one').addClass('header_out');
} else {
  $('#one').removeClass('header_out').addClass('header_in');
}
```

for the fading effect ive made

```
.header_out {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
 }

 .header_in {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
 }
```

but unfortanetly id doesnt work. i have 2 classes which fades the opacity to 0.2 and then back to 1. Hope you get my point!

Comment: its jquery UI's draggable!

Comment: Does your `if/else` statement work correctly?

Comment: yes it does. i proved it with console.log!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ewuX8/)**

Add transition to your `#one` element:

```
#one {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    background: red;
}

.out { opacity: 0; }
.in { opacity: 1; }
```

And in your jQuery:

```
// fade out
$('#one').addClass('out').removeClass('in');

// fade in
$('#one').addClass('in').removeClass('out');
```

Comment: works like a charm! thank you very much for that. But just for the clearance, what exactly was wrong at my example? Dont really get it!

Comment: @supersize It's better to write `transition` on the main element, and with classes, change the value of that property. Btw, I think that your `if` statement is missed something, you never **remove** `header_in` class from element.

Comment: `header_in`does not exist on the element before the `if` statement. anyways it does work now, thats the matter!