# Opacity transition of div

Tags: php, css, css-transitions

[Fade in and out elements with css3's transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873606/fade-in-and-out-elements-with-css3s-transition)
-- Doesn't work

I am on `index.php` and when I just go on `index.php?a=1`, DIV shows up, thats what I want, but it looks not professional if it just jumps out.

Is there possibility to use CSS3 transitions to make object first invisible and in matter of very short time period make it visible?

Comment: you want to fade in all page with transition? or only one div?

Comment: Only the one div. But if you could share also for website =P, it could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I sought for! Thanks! I'll asume it as best answer as soon as system will allow me to do it. (1 minute)

Comment: Absolutely 100% that what I wanted! Thanks.

Comment: Ehm, thats what I wanted, but, is there possibility to add more than 2 steps? Like, from, between, to... or something? :), just asking.

Comment: yes, of course, you can write 0% instead of from, 100% instead of to, and different per cents between 0% and 100% like `@-webkit-keyframes fade-in /
{
0%   {opacity:0;}
25%  {opacity:0.5;}
50%  {opacity:1;}
75%  {opacity:0.5;}
100% {opacity:1;}
}`

Comment: You saved me once more :). Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31071/discussion-between-ziyaddin-sadigov-and-rik-telner)

Comment: There is actually nothing else what I could ask, so there is no sense from just throwing this comments into chat :).

Comment: no, I just tried what is Stackoverflow's chat and turned back, beacuse, I didn't want to use chat :)

Comment: Ehm, I know its a bit akward, but I would be thankful if you would answer one more question of mine. How to make delay between 0% , 50% and 100%? Like 0%, wait for example 5 seconds, perform 50%, wait for example 5 seconds, perform 100% and how to loop keyframes, because it doesn't seem that they loop themself (tested). =) Sorry for distubring once more.

Answer (score 0):

Try a transition delay. I think it's what your searching for.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

Comment: I modified to code. But user has to hover over DIV. I want it to be automaticly done. http://jsfiddle.net/bfhZ8/ , you need to hover over it.